# Typescript does not infer the type returned by a Promise

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Let's consider the following Typescript code

```
import * as dir from 'node-dir';
export function filesAsync(fromDirPath: string) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        dir.files(fromDirPath, (err, files) => {
            if (err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve(files);
        });
    })
}
```

The type of the variable `files` is `string[]` and therefore I would expect that the type returned by the function `filesAsync` is similarly `Promise<string[]>`. What I find though using VSCode intellisense is that the type returned by the function is `Promise<{}>`.

I can fix this specifying explicitly the type used by the Promise, i.e. using `new Promise<Array<string>>(...)`. I would like to ask though if there is a way to get the correct type inferred by Typescript directly. there

Comment: Is `dir.files` properly typed?

Comment: What you should do, is declare the type of the return value of the function. Because that's what will allow TypeScript to check that what you return matches what you intend to return. That will also make it clear for the users of this function that what it returns is a Promise<string[]>, without having to read the code to discover.

Comment: @zerkms dir.files is properly type (intellisense sees that the variable `files` is of type `Array<string>`)

Comment: @JB Nizet: you are right, but it does not chage the core of my doubt: shouldn't be Typescript able to infer the type automatically?

Comment: It's a known issue, discussed in https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5254